# how do I strip off everything after a certain string [case insensitive]

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
a = "xxxxxxxxxxxHahammmmmmmmm"
```

I want to remove everything from "**haha**", such that

```
a = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

And I want to make it **case-insensitive**, so I do the following:

```
a.split(re.compile('haha', re.I))[0]
```

but it gives me a warning, but should I revise?

Comment: What's the warning? Make sure you also have `import re`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, but what you want is:

```
re.split(re.compile('haha', re.I), a)[0]
```

Check the documentation on the [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function.

Comment: Good one! Your answer should be accepted

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
import re
a = "xxxxxxxxxxxHahammmmmmmmm"
x = re.split(re.compile('haha', re.I), a)[0]
print x
```

**output:**

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
```